# Registered Trademark printing extra character

Tags: r, regex, unicode, gsub

I have some weird variables imported from SAS with unicode values for a superscript registered trademark ® and used gsub to try to make the variable print a registered trademark in R.  I made some dummy data below just to show what I did. For some reason it is printing an extra Â symbol. Does anyone know why this might be happening?

```
var1<-factor(c("prod1^{unicode 00AE}","prod2^{unicode 00AE}"))
var2<-as.factor(sapply(var1,gsub,pattern="\\{unicode 00AE\\}",replacement="\u00AE"))
> var2
[1] prod1^Â® prod2^Â®
Levels: prod1^Â® prod2^Â®
```

Comment: You may always post-process with `var2 <- gsub("Â", "", var2, fixed=TRUE)`

Answer (score 1):

Not sure whats happening with `gsub`; but `str_replace_all` provided by `stringr` is able to provide the required output:

```
> var1<-factor(c("prod1^{unicode 00AE}","prod2^{unicode 00AE}"))
> var2<-as.factor(sapply(var1,str_replace_all,pattern="\\{unicode 00AE\\}",replacement="\U00AE"))
> var2
[1] prod1^® prod2^®
Levels: prod1^® prod2^®
```

Comment: Thank you Sagar.  Your solution works brilliantly.  I still don't know why gsub didn't work but it's not a huge deal.

Answer (score 1):

The error comes from the fact that `gsub` does not handle `\uXXXX` notation in the replacement properly, even when `fixed=TRUE` is used. You actually need to set the result to UTF8 "manually". Look, this will work:

```
> res <- gsub("{unicode 00AE}", "\u00AE", x, fixed=TRUE)
> res
[1] "prod1^Â®"
> Encoding(res) <- "UTF-8"
> res
[1] "prod1^®"
```

In your case, you may just use the `replacement="®"` and it will display the result correctly:

```
> var2<-as.factor(sapply(var1,gsub,pattern="{unicode 00AE}",replacement="®", fixed=TRUE))
> var2
[1] prod1^® prod2^®
Levels: prod1^® prod2^®
```